# In a web application (war) I have a config text file. How to prevent web access to it?

Tags: java, security, servlets

In a servlet I have a config text file. How to prevent web access to it?
So that only servlet code can get access to it?
It is not encrypted and lays in the subdirectory of WebContent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything under `WEB-INF` cannot be served directly as web content; it can only be accessed by logic running server-side, like a servlet or JSP.

Comment: Careful though when fronting the web container (e.g tomcat) with a web server (e.g apache) because static files may be served directly.

Answer (score 2):

just put it in WEB-INF/Classes

Comment: Need not be specifically within 'classes'.  It can be placed anywhere within 'WEB-INF'.

Comment: Putting in classpath however greatly ease the access. Just `classLoader.getResource("file.ext")` would suffice. No need to hassle with relative/absolute filesystem paths and potential portability/maintainability pains. *Just* put it anywhere you like in the classpath (`WEB-INF/classes`, `WEB-INF/lib`, a shared classpath folder as definied in server config, etc..etc..) and don't think about it further. That's imo the only right answer. +1.

Answer (score 2):

in your `web.xml` filter out file types you don't want to be visible

**UPDATE**
@skaffman answer is enough for this case, but for more complex filtering use this:

```
    <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>Private Area</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
```